# Which sentence structure is the best?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Which one is better ? What's the difference ?

> For those who aren't aware yet, *PRODUCT NAME* is now available !
>
> For those who aren't aware of it yet, *PRODUCT NAME* is now available !

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second sentence is correct and sounds natural.

The first sentence is only formally correct but sounds strange.

The reason of the choice is clear from the semantic analysis of the adjective "*aware*".

***AWARE*** has two meanings.

According to [Merriam-Webster's Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aware#examples) :

***aware***

1: having or showing realization, perception, or knowledge

// be aware of the danger

// aware of the latest advances in medicine

2(archaic): WATCHFUL, WARY

In your case the adjective should  be used in the first meaning.

So you should use "***aware of it".***

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and a last question is "those" properly used in the sentence ?

Comment: ''For those... '' is OK. It sounds rather emphatic.

Comment: Do you have an Idea to say it in a more formal way? or is it ok?

Comment: I'll try: We would like to inform our customers who are not aware of it yet that PRODUCT NAME is now available for them!